# Applying PCA to each group of features separately to use it in a predictive model

Tags: machine-learning, pca, predictive-models, feature-selection

I have a large data-set with >100 features. Can I use PCA to reduce the dimension of each group of features instead of t applying PCA to the whole data-set?

For example, if I have 10 demographic features and 10 work-place related features in my dataset, can I apply PCA to the demographic features, extract 2 PCs, do the same to the workplace features and do the final analysis on 4 extracted PCs? How does my described method compare with applying PCA to the entire dataset at once statistically? I only intend to use this approach for an slight increase in interpretability. Is it worth it? what are the pros and cons?

The features in each feature groups are more or less correlated but not necessarily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly do this. For pros, as you have mentioned, the new features may be more interpretable/explainable. With this approach, you'll possibly end up selecting more features to describe the same amount of variance as you are limiting certain linear combinations of cross group features, though this is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: +1 I have done exactly this when working with large numbers of chemical analytes.  They tend to fall into groups of common chemical, biological, and/or physical behaviors, such as metals, chlorinated solvents, polynuclear aromatics, and so on; and often each group benefits from its own separate analysis.

Comment: @whuber I similarly was able to separate some climate data into snow-related principal components and rain-related principal components.